# Как написать providePresenter при использовании MOXY и DAGGER

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger2, moxy

Еще только изучаю MOXY и DAGGER.

У меня есть презентер, в конструктор которого нужно передать интерактор:

```
@InjectViewState
class MainPresenter(var calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor): MvpPresenter<MainView>() {  }
```

Как правильно инжектить interactoc и провайдит презентер? Если я делаю так, то приложение падает и не показывает текст ошибки:

```
class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), MainView {


    @Inject
    lateinit var calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    @ProvidePresenter
    fun providePresenter(): MainPresenter {

        return MainPresenter(calculatorInteractor)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        App.getAppComponent().injectMainActivity(this)
}
}
```

Если инжектить интерактор внутрь презентера минуя активити, вот так, то приложение работает:

```
@InjectViewState
class MainPresenter: MvpPresenter<MainView>() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor

    init {
        App.getAppComponent().injectMainPresenter(this)
    }
}
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы интерактор попадал в презентер через конструктор, чтобы облегчить тестирование презентера.

Как правильно инжектить интерактор и презентер в активити, чтобы интерактор можно было передавать в конструктор презентера?

Вот код даггера на всякий случай:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun injectMainPresenter(mainPresenter: MainPresenter)

    fun injectMainActivity(mainActivity: MainActivity)

}


@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCalculator() = Calculator()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideCalculatorInteractor(calculator: Calculator):CalculatorInteractor
            = CalculatorInteractorImpl(calculator)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решил проблемы следующим образом.

Вот так я прописал презентер:

```
@InjectViewState
class MainPresenter @Inject constructor(interactor: CalculatorInteractor): MvpPresenter<MainView>() {

    private val calculatorInteractor: CalculatorInteractor = interactor

}
```

Вот так я прописал активити:

```
class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), MainView {

    @Inject
    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var mainPresenter: MainPresenter

    @ProvidePresenter
    fun provide() = mainPresenter

    init{
        App.getAppComponent().injectMainActivity(this)
    }
}
```